# Links in the navbar redirects me to wrong path

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I've started working on an authentication app, and the navbar links of register and login are not redirecting me to the correct destination. They seem to be working fine on the landing index page but not on any other page.

[site with working links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYINd.png)

[same site where the links start to break](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E99DZ.png)

**app.js**

```
var app = express();

var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");


var users = require("./routes/users.js");


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded([{extended:false}]));
app.set("view engine","ejs");

app.use(express.static("public"));



app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.render("index");
});

app.post("/hello",function(req,res){
    res.redirect("/");
});

app.use("/users",users);


app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("server has been started!!!");
});
```

**routes/users.js**

```
var router = express.Router();


router.get("/login",function(req,res){
    res.render("login");
});

router.post("/login",function(req,res){
    res.send("hello from login");
});

router.get("/register",function(req,res){
    res.render("register");
});

router.post("/register",function(req,res){
    res.send("hello from post");
});

module.exports = router;
```

**views/partials/header.ejs**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="users/register">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="users/login">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

***views/index.ejs***

```
<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Welcome to Index page</h1>

    <p>Authentication test app</p>
</div>
</div>
<%- include('partials/footer')%>
```

**views/register.ejs**

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control input-form" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email" name="email">
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputUsername">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-form" id="exampleInputUsername" placeholder="Username" name="username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control input-form" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" name="password">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>

<%- include('./partials/footer')%>
```

**views/login.ejs**

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control input-form" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email" name="email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control input-form" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" name="password">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>

<%- include('./partials/footer')%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to append a slash to the hrefs in `views/partials/header.ejs` like so:

```
<li><a href="/users/register">Register</a></li>
<li><a href="/users/login">Login</a></li>
```

Reason:

Using `users/login` will append the path to the current document level, not the the root of the site. So if you are at the url `localhost:3000/users`, the href `users/login` will expand to `localhost:3000/users/users/login`, whereas the href `/users/login` will expand to `localhost:3000/users/login`